Ignite 2.16: Work directory does not exist and cannot be created: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work
We are facing this error in ignite 2.16.0 installation in kubernetes pods.
Activating without user credentials
Running /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/bin/control.sh --host ignite-service --set-state ACTIVE --yes
WARNING: Unknown module: jdk.internal.jvmstat specified to --add-exports
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2 (file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/libs/ignite-core-2.16.0.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Work directory does not exist and cannot be created: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.commandline.CommandHandler.setupJavaLogger(CommandHandler.java:183)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.commandline.CommandHandler.<init>(CommandHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.commandline.CommandHandler.main(CommandHandler.java:164)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Work directory does not exist and cannot be created: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.workDirectory(IgniteUtils.java:10027)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.defaultWorkDirectory(IgniteUtils.java:9967)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.commandline.CommandHandler.setupJavaLogger(CommandHandler.java:175)

We have the following settings inside the ignite STS yaml file -
- mountPath: "/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work"
  name: "ignite-work"

We have the following settings inside the ignite docker file -
RUN mkdir -p /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work
 
#Grant permission to work directory
RUN chmod 777 /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work 
 
ENV IGNITE_HOME /opt/ignite/apache-ignite
WORKDIR /opt/ignite

With the same settings ignite 2.14 was working perfectly, but it's not working in 2.16. Can you please suggest us what other changes required.
Here is the dockerfile -
# Start from Java 8 based on Alpine Linux image
ARG JDK_VERSION=8
FROM AAA.net/openjdk:11-jre-slim

# Settings
ENV IGNITE_HOME /opt/ignite/apache-ignite
WORKDIR /opt/ignite

# Add missing software

# Copy main binary archive
COPY apache-ignite* apache-ignite

# Copy sh files and set permission
COPY run.sh $IGNITE_HOME/

# Grant permission to copy optional libs
RUN chmod 777 ${IGNITE_HOME}/libs

# Grant permission to create work directory
RUN chmod 777 ${IGNITE_HOME}

# Grant permission to execute entry point
RUN chmod 555 $IGNITE_HOME/run.sh

USER 2000
# Entry point
CMD $IGNITE_HOME/run.sh

# Container port exposure
EXPOSE 11211 47100 47500 49112 10800 8080

And this is the configurations that are passed to the dockerfile -
build_ignite_docker()

{

    mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}/IGNITE_BASE

    cd ${WORKDIR}/IGNITE_BASE
 
    cp -rf ${DOCKERFILE_DIR}/Dockerfile.uiv-ignite .
 
    cp -rf ${DOCKERFILE_DIR}/../scripts/ignite_startup_script/run.sh .
 
 
  # Download ignite binary

  wget https://AAA.net/artifactory/archive-apache-org-dist/ignite/2.16.0/apache-ignite-2.16.0-bin.zip
 
 
  # Unzip ignite binary zip

  unzip apache-ignite-2.16.0-bin.zip
 
    # Deleted the zip file

  rm -f apache-ignite-2.16.0-bin.zip
 
    docker build -t ${DOCKER_REPO}/uiv-ignite:2.16-1 -f Dockerfile.uiv-ignite .

    docker tag ${DOCKER_REPO}/uiv-ignite:2.16-1 ${DOCKER_REPO}/uiv-ignite:2.16-1

}

Thanks a lot in advance.
Nirmalya

If you're building your own Docker image, you should probably share the Dockerfile.

Hi Stephen, I have edited the original post with the dockerfile. Please have a look.

Why build your own image? At face value, there does not appear to be much different from the official one.
